# Permission denied when trying to run a job as myuser, but error says root doesn't have enough permissions

Tags: java, hadoop, permissions, hdfs

I'm trying to get Hadoop MapReduce working, but keep facing access problems. 
I'm not sure what the problem is, whether it is configuration or something else.

When I'm running, for example, this wordcount

> hadoop jar /usr/share/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount /user/myuser/input.txt /user/myuser/output.txt

I'm getting the following error:

```
14/09/10 20:15:51 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/09/10 20:15:51 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201409101946_0010
14/09/10 20:15:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/09/10 20:15:52 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409101946_0010_m_000002_0,         Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201409101946_0010_m_000002_0:
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:         
org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=root, 
access=EXECUTE, inode="job_201409101946_0010":hadoop:supergroup:rwx------
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
...
```

Obviously, user=root cannot access directory owned by the user hadoop. But the problem is that I'm running the job as myuser and I'm not sure why root is involved here at all. Do you know what can be causing this issue?

Comment: could you check the user group privileges for your JAR location

Comment: this particular jar is owned by root, but I had exactly the same problem with another jar, this is owned by myuser.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `/user/myuser/` should be a path on HDFS, not a local path. Then, it needs to exist, so, if it doesn't, run:

`hadoop dfs -mkdir /user/myuser/` and then 
`hadoop dfs -chown myuser:groopOfMyuser /user/myuser/` , where `groupOfMyuser` is the group to which `myuser` belongs.

To check whether it exists run:
`hadoop dfs -ls /user/`

Then, to upload your files to the input dir on HDFS, use the command:

`hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /local/path/input.txt /user/myuser/`

Note that input and output paths should be directories (on HDFS) and not files. So, the correct command to run your programm would be:

`hadoop jar /usr/share/hadoop/hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar wordcount /user/myuser /user/myuser/output`

Finally, check if the hadoop dirs (`$HADOOP_HOME`) are owned by `myuser` or `hadoop` or whatever and run the jars as the one who owns them, or change their ownership with `chown`.

(Assuming you use the old API, but you can easily find the equivalent commands in the new API, as well.)

Comment: /user/myuser/ is a path on HDFS and is owned by myuser. This part should be ok. The code didn't actually reach any reading anyway. The permission denied I get is when hadoop is trying to access/create temporary job file (most likely in staging dir), for some reason it is doing so as root. So I think the second part of your answer might actually resolve the issue, I will give it a try.